# How to automatically collect HP server service tag from datacenter?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

I wonder if there is any automated tool to get HP serial number from my datacenter, because I'd like to do server refresh and there are more than hundreds of it that I need to identify its base warranty up to date ?

ANy help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hier Student,. Have student make pictures of service tags. They are not in the computer, so this is your only way. Fire person responsible for not tracking business relevant information (legal obligation) when hardware came in, then send him the invoice for the student (gross neglect = legal obligation to pay for damage).

Comment: @TomTom, the Service Tag may be read by appropriate software.

Comment: @TomTom - I advise you read the answers below before re-evaluating your assertion!

Comment: @TomTom, do what now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool for this exact question you have asked. It's called HP Systems Insight Manager, coupled with SNMP/WMI protocols and a small server-side client it will make your automation processes very smooth. There are a lot of possibilities with the tool, as i've used this extensively within an enterprise. I suggest you check it out.

http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/servers/management/hpsim/index.html

Comment: well I'm about to rebuild the HP SIM into v 6.23 since the current SIM server is broken

Comment: story of my life, i hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 9):

You don't mention OS, however:

Linux: You should be able to get at least the Product Name and Serial from the output of `dmidecode`

Windows: Run the following on the command line: `wmic csproduct get vendor,name,identifyingnumber`. You can  also run `wmic /node:computername ....` to get the information remotely.

Comment: +1 for dmidecode - it's an superb tool and gives you access to a lot of information which people believe are hidden from the OS.

Comment: I <3 WMIC, it's the best thing since pstools IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

HP has a product that can help gather all this information for you.  It's called [Asset Manager](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-85-121%5E1480_4000_100__).

Comment: thanks Mr. Denny is it this one: https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-85-121^1480_4000_100__ ? doesn't seems to be freeware ?

Comment: Yep, that's the one.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the host names or IP addresses, you can use SNMP to fetch this info.

Having just tried this on a few of my servers, they all respond with their correct serial number with the command `snmpget SERVERNAME 1.3.6.1.4.1.232.2.2.2.1.0`.